# How to call Most Viewed code in Listing page?

Tags: magento-1.7

I got Most Viewed extension from Magento Connect. Now I want to write code as shown in screenshot. By default Most Viewed code is called in Home Page but I want to show in Listing page.

[image]

Here I added attribute i.e most-viewed in Manage Attribute (in admin)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the extension name

Comment: @krishna Tatva_Catalogextensions https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/top-seller-new-feature-most-viewed-catalog-sale-recently-ordered-all-products-7-in-one-catalog-by-etatvasoft.html

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev In admin on CMS, Pages - In that I have added new page - It is displayed there but I want to display in link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static block in Admin and keep the below code.

```
{{block type="catalogextensions/mostviewed_home_list" name="mostviewed_list" template="catalogextensions/home_mostviewed.phtml"}}
```

As you shown in the screen shoot select `Display Mode -> Products` and static block and select static block you create in `CMS Block -> myblock` and save

Check the specific category.